# How to get the set of the items by id with pagination in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-partitioning

I have a table `Topic`, with multiple topics with `topicId` as **primary key** and `updatedTime` as **sort key**.

I can able to fetch single topic by `topicId`, but my requirement is to fetch more than 1 topics by id and also I need pagination.

Can you please suggest if I need to use GSI or change schema to achieve it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No your design is fine, you just need to use [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) API call.

And you can paginate the results if needed. Learn more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html)

If you need to obtain many orders with a single request then you can use `ExecuteStatement` which allows you to search for up to 50 partition keys in a single request. You can paginate just as you would with the low level Query, except using PartiQL it'll be specified on the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Leeroy Hannigan, how do I query multiple primary keys in a single call to dynamodb and also with pagination

Comment: By primary key I believe you mean partition key, you can either do individual Query calls or use ExecuteStatement that can take up to 50 keys.

Comment: I am using aws-sdk with node, ExecuteStatement is for partiQL right.
I am sorry I don't have idea. Can you reference me some doc, does it also allow me to paginate ?

Comment: It's PartiQL yes. And can be paginated by passing the LastEvaluatedKey as a WHERE clause.

Comment: Is it okay to use PartiQL, currently I am using node aws sdk with general dynamodb queries

Comment: Didn't the partiQL will cause the SCAN operation in dynamodb for my use case?
i.e SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE Orders IN (100, 200, 300);
Does it make whole table scan or it is efficient enough to look at the partition

Comment: PartiQL is not an SDK, it's just a different way of defining the API syntax.

Comment: So long as `Orders` is your partition key it'll execute Query API.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and add about ExecuteStatement, then I can accept it. Does PartQl help to paginate the nested attribute